# iOS objc-class-ref in Error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

Where is the mistake?

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GPPSignIn"

Screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Have you added the Google+ client static library? It seems you haven't.

Answer (score 1):

First Tell Me if You have to Putted any `framework` as copy-paste ?? in most of cases this type of issue created.

Generally this Types of Error Occur when your class `.m` file is not store/putted under `Compile Sources`

In This case you need to add manually this `.m` file to `Compile Sources`

**Following step Describe how to put `.m` file in `Compile Sources` manually**

```
Select Project Form Project Manager
  |
  | 
  Targets
       |
       |
     Build Phases
          |
          |
        Compile Sources
                |
                |
        Click on '+' button and add .m file in it
```

This is Step For how to put file manually in `Compile Sources`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use a library that you haven't actually linked in to your target.

Make sure that you have all of the libraries and frameworks you're using either under "linked frameworks and libraries" in your target's summary tab, or make sure that the static library can be found in your header and library search paths.