# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, xcode7

My app is working in certain device simulator and some gives me an error like this:

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/username/Documents/projectname/libSVGKit-iOS.2.0.0.a, 
  missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/wendy/Documents/projectname/libSVGKit-iOS.2.0.0.a (2 slices)

 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SVGKFastImageView", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FrontView.o
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SVGKImage", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FrontView.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to seeinvocation)
```

I've been searching for quite a  while and I'm still left clueless on how to solve this, can anybody help me with this?

Comment: try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848520/ios-objc-class-ref-in-erorr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
    "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SVGKFastImageView", referenced from:
```

this tells us implementation missing for i386 architecture (Simulator). If you are pretty sure the library added properly,

1) try the same process in device.

2) Rebuild your library for simulator and add it to run it on simulator.